# run i3wm as Mate DE window manager

Tags: mate, i3-wm

I just installed i3wm on **Ubuntu Mate 16.04**.

I'm using it alone, but I should "resolve" all the things like power-management, automount and so on. Since I do not have time I would start using i3wm instead of `marco` window manager on the Mate DE. I have the version 1.18.

I followed the guides on the internet by doing these commands:
`dconf write /org/mate/desktop/session/required-components/windowmanager "'i3'"`
and
`dconf write /org/mate/desktop/background/show-desktop-icons "false"`

and trough `dconf-editor > org/mate/desktop/session` I removed ‘filemanager’ from `required-components-list`

But it does not work (after a log out). I open a window on the top left corner and no other. It does not respond with i3 keyboard shortcut. The only thing that I can do is reset `marco`.

Where is the problem?
I really like the `tilling` thing, but for now, I want to use it with the DE first

Answer (score 0):

```
$ pkill marco
$ i3
```

Then log out and in again.
I don't know if it is a proper way to do this, but it works for me.